# Auto mounting mobible SSD is low in Ubuntu20.04

Tags: ssd, automount

My OS is ubuntu20.04, for mechanical mobile HDD, such WD of size 2T, the processing is fast, but for mobile SSD(Crucial X6), the auto mounting processing is slow, it takes almost 60s,In windows 10, the processing is fast as WD HDD,so I guess the problem is casused by ubuntu20.04,  the jounal infomation is below

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2024-03-10 23:05:53 CST, end at Mon 2024-03-18 13:51:30 CST. --
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd-journald[543]: Journal stopped
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Shutting down.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Reached target Reboot.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Finished Reboot.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: systemd-reboot.service: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Reached target Final Step.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Reached target Shutdown.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: systemd-remount-fs.service: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Reached target Unmount All Filesystems.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Deactivated swap /swapfile.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: swapfile.swap: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped Create System Users.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Deactivating swap /swapfile...
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped target Swap.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounting /run/snapd/ns...
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted /run/snapd/ns/snap-store.mnt.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: run-snapd-ns-snap\x2dstore.mnt.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Removed slice system-clean\x2dmount\x2dpoint.slice.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/hitbuyi/Crucial_X6 mount point.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-hitbuyi-Crucial_X6.service: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/hitbuyi/Crucial_X6 mount point...
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/hitbuyi/Crucial_X6.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: media-hitbuyi-Crucial_X6.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Stopped target Mounting snaps.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for webkitgtk-6-gnome-2204, revision 31.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-webkitgtk\x2d6\x2dgnome\x2d2204-31.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for vlc, revision 3721.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-vlc-3721.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for viztube, revision 51.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-viztube-51.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for viztube, revision 50.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-viztube-50.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for subtitle-edit, revision 7.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-subtitle\x2dedit-7.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snapd, revision 20671.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-snapd-20671.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 959.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-959.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for snap-store, revision 638.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: snap-snap\x2dstore-638.mount: Succeeded.
3月 18 13:19:56 hitbuyi-Dell-G15-5511 systemd[1]: Unmounted Mount unit for shadowsocks-rust, revision 689.
```

How to solve it?